problem installing canvas on the discord bot i'm doing
When I run npm install canvas I get the following error in the console:
npm warn deprecated inflight@1.0.6: This module is not supported, and leaks memory. Do not use it. Check out lru-cache if you want a good and tested way to coalesce async requests by a key value, which is much more comprehensive and powerful.
npm warn deprecated npmlog@5.0.1: This package is no longer supported.
npm warn deprecated rimraf@3.0.2: Rimraf versions prior to v4 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated are-we-there-yet@2.0.0: This package is no longer supported.
npm warn deprecated gauge@3.0.2: This package is no longer supported.
npm error code 1
npm error path C:\Users\SrTecc\Desktop\project\node_modules\canvas
npm error command failed
npm error command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --update-binary
npm error Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\SrTecc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --update-binary --module=C:\Users\SrTecc\Desktop\project\node_modules\canvas\build\Release\canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=C:\Users\SrTecc\Desktop\project\node_modules\canvas\build\Release --napi_version=9 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v127' (1)
npm error node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm error node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@1.0.11
npm error node-pre-gyp info using node@22.12.0 | win32 | x64
npm error (node:17172) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The punycode module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
npm error (Use node --trace-deprecation ... to show where the warning was created)
npm error node-pre-gyp http GET https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.11.2/canvas-v2.11.2-node-v127-win32-unknown-x64.tar.gz
npm error node-pre-gyp ERR! install response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.11.2/canvas-v2.11.2-node-v127-win32-unknown-x64.tar.gz
npm error node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for canvas@2.11.2 and node@22.12.0 (node-v127 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
npm error node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.11.2/canvas-v2.11.2-node-v127-win32-unknown-x64.tar.gz
npm error gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm error gyp info using node-gyp@11.0.0
npm error gyp info using node@22.12.0 | win32 | x64
npm error gyp info ok
npm error gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm error gyp info using node-gyp@11.0.0
npm error gyp info using node@22.12.0 | win32 | x64
npm error gyp info find Python using Python version 3.11.9 found at "C:\Users\SrTecc\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe"
npm error gyp ERR! find VS
npm error gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
npm error gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
npm error gyp ERR! find VS could not use PowerShell to find Visual Studio 2017 or newer, try re-running with '--loglevel silly' for more details.
npm error gyp ERR! find VS
npm error gyp ERR! find VS Failure details: undefined
npm error gyp ERR! find VS could not use PowerShell to find Visual Studio 2017 or newer, try re-running with '--loglevel silly' for more details.
npm error gyp ERR! find VS
npm error gyp ERR! find VS Failure details: undefined
npm error gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2017 as it is only supported up to Node.js 21
npm error gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2017 as it is only supported up to Node.js 21
npm error gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2017 as it is only supported up to Node.js 21
npm error gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2015 as it is only supported up to Node.js 18
npm error gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
npm error gyp ERR! find VS
npm error gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm error gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
npm error gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
npm error gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
npm error gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
npm error gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm error gyp ERR! find VS
npm error gyp ERR! configure error
npm error gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
npm error gyp ERR! stack at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Users\SrTecc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:118:11)
npm error gyp ERR! stack at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio (C:\Users\SrTecc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:74:17)
npm error gyp ERR! stack at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:105:5)
npm error gyp ERR! stack at async createBuildDir (C:\Users\SrTecc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:112:18)
npm error gyp ERR! stack at async run (C:\Users\SrTecc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js:81:18)
npm error gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19045
npm error gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\SrTecc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--update-binary" "--module=C:\Users\SrTecc\Desktop\project\node_modules\canvas\build\Release\canvas.node" "--module_name=canvas" "--module_path=C:\Users\SrTecc\Desktop\project\node_modules\canvas\build\Release" "--napi_version=9" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v127"
npm error gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\SrTecc\Desktop\project\node_modules\canvas
npm error gyp ERR! node -v v22.12.0
npm error gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v11.0.0
npm error gyp ERR! not ok
npm error node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
npm error node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\SrTecc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --update-binary --module=C:\Users\SrTecc\Desktop\project\node_modules\canvas\build\Release\canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=C:\Users\SrTecc\Desktop\project\node_modules\canvas\build\Release --napi_version=9 --node_abi_napi=napi
--napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v127' (1)
npm error node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess. (C:\Users\SrTecc\Desktop\project\node_modules@mapbox\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:89:23)
npm error node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1101:16)
npm error node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:304:5)
npm error node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19045
npm error node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\SrTecc\Desktop\project\node_modules\@mapbox\node-pre-gyp\bin\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--update-binary"
npm error node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\SrTecc\Desktop\project\node_modules\canvas
npm error node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v22.12.0
npm error node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v1.0.11
npm error node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok

Please re-format the question. Its very hard to read the question let alone understand.

You are using Node.js v22.12.0, which is very new and may not yet be fully supported by all packages.
I think you should the version 20
nvm install 20
nvm use 20

